# javascript interpreter of native executable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering about running Windows or gnu/Linux executables from within a webpage.  Just to be clear, I am NOT talking about any sort of Remote Desktop thing.  What I am envisioning is a user fetching the website, which will come with a hidden file that is executable code or represents native executable code like when you rename a .exe to .txt.  The website would then proceed to use JavaScript or a similar web based method to interpret the native executable or file representing it, effectively "running" it within the webpage. All this could be done with no communication with a remote host.

So, what I really want to know is, has this or something similar been done before?  If so, how was it implemented? Is it even possible? How could I do it?  What about a simulated window system in the site for gui applications?

Comment: You're effectively asking if it's possible to implement a VM in javascript.  Interesting question, but **way** too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's probably been done before, it's usually called hacking, and browser vendors spend billions trying to avoid it by creating a sandbox inside the browser with no access to the users filesystem..

Comment: You're trying to run code on a user's machine without his/her knowledge? Interesting

Comment: No!!  I mean a vm, not JavaScript hacking!  I'm sorry the question was so unclear.  Thanks andyg

Comment: Well, an *emulator*, for instance the X86 emulator andyg is mentioning, can be written in javascript, but you can't transfer hidden files to a client, nor can you load those files into your "VM" from the clients computer without asking for permission, and probably having the client change the security setting of the browser as well.

Comment: _"The website would then proceed to use JavaScript or a similar web based method to interpret the native executable or file representing it, effectively "running" it within the webpage."_ What are you trying to run? Which "native executable" are you referencing?

Comment: Omg I am not trying to hack I'm sorry I posted an ill-formed question

Answer (score 3):

As @Tibrogargan mentioned in the comments, this is indeed asking about building a VM in Javascript. [Fabrice Bellard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabrice_Bellard), the one behind FFMpeg and QEmu, has written a VM in Javascript. You can play with it at http://bellard.org/jslinux/, but it's not open-source. A couple open-source projects that might be of interest are [JsDOSBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsdosbox/) and [PC Emulator in JavaScript](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jspcemulator/). They appear to both include a graphics-capable display.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise answer.  I LOVE open source projects!

Comment: And I guess this is a vm I asked about.  I was thinking of interpreters when I wrote this question.